# Show delivery days in product page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3

I want to show a custom message on the product page, delivery days message. like
"next day delivery". is it possible?

Comment: Refer the file `catalog_product_view.xml` in catalog module and  choose the containers or move the element as per your need where you can add a new template and view model. In view Model you can write logic to get the deliver days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can follow two approach to achieve your goal.

1. Tweaking the layout file.
2. Customize the template.

Navigate to your theme file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/
```

Here you can find lot of  .phtml file which is responsible for displaying the product details page.

If you are unsure which file display what then please enable your template hints from the admin panel.

Comment: and more detailed?

Comment: Check my detail answer